# spacecraft thermal dataset

Tags: spacecraft, thermal, temperature, reference-request, telemetry

For a high-school academic project, I would like to plot a graph of change in satellite's temperature over time.

Thus, (I think), I'm looking for real-time temperature data of sort of any (preferably earth-orbiting) spacecraft.

I got advice that this should be available together with public-open telemetry.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes...the data is available for some missions**, but it will take some time to get used to what it means and how to read it.  Programming experience would be helpful.  Microsoft Excel can *probably* do it, but personally I'd go with a scientific computing language like various Python plugins or, if you have access, MATLAB (or its free cousin, Octave).

[Here](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/dataset/display.action?id=PSSB-00615)  is a link to one such dataset for the EPOXI mission, but it is not Earth orbital. It was an extension of the Deep Impact mission in solar orbit.  Scroll to the very bottom of the page for a link to the data.  Click on any of the files you'll eventually get to, they are just text files and your browser can open and download them.

In general, the website I linked above has access to *tons* of datasets from real missions.  Many contain raw scientific data which are basically incomprehensible to people not in the specific field of the specific instrument that produced it, but lots of it is engineering data.  They don't make it easy to find the data (the search sucks) and the data is **extremely** tersely explained, but I'll bet if you dig around that server for a while you'll find what you need.